# My Tablet PC (Windows) doesn't exit the boot screen anymore

Tags: windows, boot

If I start the tablet PC, i don't even see the windows logo anymore, I'm stuck at the American megatrends bootscreen. I also can't enter bios. Thanks for your help!
Of course I already tried pressing del or esc but it didn't respond.

The device is a chiligreen E-Board MW060 running windows 10

**Update: I just inserted an usb stick and now I have full access to the bios, but I still can't boot.**

[this is where i'm stuck](http://free-picload.com/images/2019/02/14/IMG_20190214_212445.jpg)

Comment: Unclear: Add a screenshot of the screen; what have you tried; which tablet PC?

Comment: I've added these things

Comment: I can access the bios now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either a hardware problem or the BIOS is destroyed.

As the BIOS hangs, you cannot get into it to reset it and cannot boot from a boot USB
in order to update it from there.

The last remaining option is described in the article
[Clearing the BIOS, CMOS and NVRAM By Removing and Reseating the CMOS Battery](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln284985/how-to-perform-a-bios-or-cmos-reset-and-or-clear-the-nvram-on-your-dell-system?lang=en#Shortcut_3).
But as I don't know your tablet, I cannot give precise instructions.
Also, tablets are built very compact, so opening it up is risky, and in addition
I can't read the language of the chiliGREEN website.

I would really suggest getting in touch with chiliGREEN Support and asking for
advice. If the tablet is still under warranty, using it is your best option.

Comment: Did my answer help with the problem? If it did please accept it (tick the V sign).

Comment: I can access the bios now